# Windows server 2016 Security Log - Remove extra description text?

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-event-log

Preface once again: I'm a Linux admin.

Is there any way to reduce the verbosity of Windows Server Security Log messages? For example, **every** logon event "4624" has this extra text describing what a logon event is. Yes, I know what a logon event is. At this point I even know what event ID 4624 is. And if I don't, I can just look up the details.

Example:

```
    Computer = "dc1.example.com";
    EventCode = 4624;
    EventIdentifier = 4624;
    Logfile = "Security";
...snip...
...
...useful info...
...THIS:
This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is generated on the computer that was accessed.

The subject fields indicate etc etc etc etc - 1.6k worth!!
```

All the extra verbosity is crushing my logging service!

I've found exactly one other person on the internet with this problem, which I find very surprising! And that one person had a Splunk-specific solution. I'd prefer a Windows-native solution, since I'm not using Splunk.

Comment: What is your 'logging service' ? Do you use Windows Event Forwarding to collect these events?

Comment: Sumo Logic, a "cloud" log collection service. There's an agent that sends it to the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Windows events exist in two formats: Xml, and Rendered Text. Usually you only need the Xml data. If the Sumo collectors are configured to send Rendered Text (seems like it), 80% of your log data is useless redundant junk.

The "renderMessages" setting seems applicable. default: True

Flag indicating if full event messages are collected (true) or just core event metadata (false)

https://help.sumologic.com/03Send-Data/Sources/03Use-JSON-to-Configure-Sources/JSON-Parameters-for-Installed-Sources#Local_Windows_Event_Log_Source

Comment: thank you, this may be helpful. was hoping for a Windows-centric solution, but this will do if it works.

Comment: I used this method; it makes the messages more cryptic, but way smaller

Comment: Note that the Windows event log itself only contains the event number and any associated information such as a user identifier.  It is the software you're using to retrieve the events that decides how to present them to you, including the decision whether to look up the descriptive text associated with that event number.  So there really isn't any generic solution to make Windows "not do that", because it isn't Windows that's "doing that" to begin with. :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is an option if you do Windows Event Forwarding - Windows Event Collector subscription. Then you can change the events with sending the <ContentFormat> as "Events" instead of "RenderedText".

```
wecutil ss <name of subscription> /cf:events
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're worried about disk usage, then you can set the event log to "archive when full" and enable deduplication on the volume. You'll need something to manage the logs because otherwise they will grow forever.